# Import of C++ module appears within extern "C" language linkage specification on Xcode 15

Tags: c++, xcode15

If I have the code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _ZLIB_H
#include "zlib.h"
#endif
...
```

We know that should not use #include in extern "C" { ... }, but many of current code and library using this way.

My question is:

That type of code can build without error on Xcode 14 and previous Xcode versions as default. But that code will has error of "Import of C++ module appears within extern "C" language linkage specification" when compile on Xcode 15.

So what has changed in Xcode 15 and how to overcome that issue to make Xcode 25 can compile without error as Xcode 14.

Thank you.

I can't find which setting option to make it works.

Comment: Is it an actual *build* error, or a warning from the IDE itself? If it's an actual build error, then please [edit] your question to include a copy-paste of the full and complete build log.

Comment: You can hide the error if you uncheck:

*Xcode > Build Settings > Apple Clang Module Verifier - Options > Enable Module Verifier*

Answer (score -2):

The problem occurs with Xcode 15 RC.

With the official release of Xcode 15, the error was gone.